# VMWARE: How to trunk 4 x 1Gbit Ports for a Virtual Machine Port Group

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, trunk

Yesterday i asked this Question:

[VMware NIC Teaming - How to gain more than 1Gbit/s copy speed between two VMs?](https://serverfault.com/questions/741907/vmware-nic-teaming-how-to-gain-more-than-1gbit-s-copy-speed-between-two-vms)

I had a missunderstanding about the "NIC Teaming" --> "Load Balancing" options in VMWare network configuration.

So now my Question is how can i trunk 4 x 1 Gbit Ports for a virutal machine port group. My current configuration can be seen here:
[image]

Problem is, that i have a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM which should be faster than 1 Gbit/s. But with my current configuration this isn't possible - a VM will never be faster than 1Gbit/s with that config.

At the moment i can not use 10 Gbit Ports... :-/

Comment: a) what's your switch config and b) what does this Windows VM talk to and what talks to it and c) which license do you have?

Comment: Hi chopper3, thx. for reply. a) i don't have access to the switches. -> But my co-worker can set up different trunking-options for me. b) it doesn't really matter. The VM is a file system which needs some more speed for the file backup. But even if i have other ways to solve this i am also still currios about the trunking... c) only standard... :-/ which license would support trunking?

Comment: ah - a) you pretty much need to configure your switches exactly right to get a benefit in this situation, b) it does matter a great deal actually, presumably it's talking to lots of different clients? and c) only Enterprise Plus supports LACP which would be the best solution for this. Shame you can't 10Gig the lot, makes life much easier

Comment: a) i know but the co-worker would do this for me b) not that much... its more like an archive-File server but is very big >10TB. so Backup takes a lot of time... but i have to solve this over an other way... c) I feared this answer!! :-) So only with Enterprise plus i can make a usefull trunking? Damn... But maybe that is a good argument to get finally some 10Gig Ports.... If there is no other posibility for me you can write your comment as answer and i will mark it as solution... thx Chopper3

Comment: You can trunk how you like, it's load-balancing that's the issue - personally I only ever use active/standby setups but that's my choice, I know lots of people like LACP and trust it but it's complex to setup and needs help from the network people. Oh and let's see what other people say first, I don't need the SF rep tbh :)

Comment: Adding on here but [Great Article on this very question](https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2015/03/26/load-balancing-vsphere-vswitch-uplinks.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LACP](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.networking.doc/GUID-0D1EF5B4-7581-480B-B99D-5714B42CD7A9.html) might help you.

However, you won't get more than 1 Gbit/s for a single connection. That's because LACP chooses the uplink to use through a combination of different parameters. If source and destination MAC, IP and port stay the same LACP will always use the same uplink. But LACP can give you more overall bandwith.

Btw: your virtual switch is effectively the access switch for the VMs. So if you connect it directly to your 10 Gbit backbone you'll get a lot more than with LACP and Gbit uplinks;-)

Comment: Hi Mario, thx. i know this but the point is, that i don't get an direct 10Gbit connection... :-/

Comment: Well then it's LACP or [route based on IP hash](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.networking.doc/GUID-809743E1-F366-4454-9BA5-9C3FD8C56D32.html). You won't get more than 1 Gbit/s for a single connection, though... there's no way to achieve this as far as I know.