# Is it possible to trunk ESXi 6.5 with HP 1820-48G?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, trunk

I am trying to setup trunk between those two (ESXi 6.5 with HP 1820-48G) and nothing seems to work.

I have read vmware kb article (can not insert link) and no luck.

These are my setup options, brute forced them all and nothing is any good. I am either not getting connection or there are strange problems with connection out and resolving dns.

ESXi options:
[image]

Switch options:
[image]

Cant really do much debugging... is it even possible?

Comment: There's no reason to run link-aggregation on ESXi _unless_ you're using a distributed switch (which requires vSphere and top-tier licensing). What problem are you looking to solve with this?

Comment: This single host is sandbox for testing so I wanted to add more bandwidth for moving stuff around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, your goal of adding bandwidth really won't work the way you expect.

See: [VMware NIC Teaming - How to gain more than 1Gbit/s copy speed between two VMs?](https://serverfault.com/questions/741907/vmware-nic-teaming-how-to-gain-more-than-1gbit-s-copy-speed-between-two-vms)

If more bandwidth is required, you'll have to move to 10GbE networking.

Comment: I understand that I cannot exceed 1Gbit on single transfer, but I expect more people connecting to several vms. Improving that is my goal, maybe I expressed myself poorly...

Comment: People ask this type of question often. In practice, nobody does this. If you need to transfer > 120MB/s in aggregate, static link-aggregation in ESXi won't do it for you.